# QGIS - Creating a map that uses live data

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mapping, wampserver, qgis

I am very new to qgis and qgis server, which I have downloaded the plugins of Openlayers, and qgis2web with qgis 2.18.  As an added note, I have a wordpress site which the map will go into.  I have created a map with multiple layers.  Hooked up database's data to it to populate what midwest state counties people had went to, who had went to those counties, and how many times they have been to that county.  Even colored coded it to show case results.  Now I am ready to put the map on the web.  Here is my Question:  How do you put the map on the web so it will show live data from our database we are using?

I have create a map using qgis2web and exporting it and then use place it within my wordpress's wamp server and was able to display it using an iframe. BUT, I assume it only created that one static instance of the map. If the datbase were to update, it will not show the correct mapping results.  In so, I want to keep the map constantly connected to the database so it will show live data.  How would I show live data and having the map constantly update?  I think I have downloaded the qgis server as well, and hopefully set that up correctly. Was thinking of doing that way as well, but no luck.  Any help where to start, or what to do is appreciated.

Comment: Not QGis but, depending on what your goals are, Carto may be well positioned to provide the utility you are looking for in a bit more user-friendly wrapper. Here's a blog post about hooking it up to real time data: https://carto.com/learn/guides/data-and-sql/sync-real-time-data

Comment: Similar kind of work.https://ams.confex.com/ams/97Annual/webprogram/Paper304264.html Watch the included video presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export a map using qgis2web it will export your layers as a static files. Using the latest version (2.22.0) it goes into the "data" folder and will create a .js file with the geographic information stored as a geojson (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON). Now for a feed with live data this will definitely not work.

To achieve a live feed there are a number of ways to build one. There are certain services like Qgis Cloud (https://qgiscloud.com/) or Carto (http://carto.com/) that allow you to do that. However, these service might not necessarily suit your needs. (In Carto's case only the base functionality is free of charge. The features for building a live feed cost.)

If you want to build it yourself I'm not aware of a "simple solution". There are quite a few different ways to build a web GIS. In short you'd need your geodatabase (like postgres with postgis), a map server software (like geoserver) that renders the geographic information in the database as WMS/WFS services that in return can be visualised using Openlayers, Leaflet or other javascript libraries. The resulting map can be implemented on your site (Some CMS come with plugins that ease the process of implementing mapping services. I don't know about wordpress though).

In any case, it is probably best to just refer to already existing answers and tutorials:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using Rethinkdb. It pushes JSON to your apps in real time.  https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb